# $f(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}(1-\left | t \right |)dt(x\geq -1)$,The area of the curve $f(X)$ and x-axis

Tags: definite-integrals, area

$$ f(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}(1-\left | t \right |)dt(x\geq -1)$$ ,The area of the curve $f(X)$ and x-axis
When I did the calculations, I used wolfram alpha.It is the use of a digital $1 + \sqrt2 $Look at this question, I do not know how this number is how come! I have tried wolframOh, it doesn't work.
[This is what I do, access may be a little slow.](http://mm2017.top/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/20191005080754.png)

$    f(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}(1-\left | t \right |)dt     =   -\dfrac{x\left|x\right|-2x-1}{2}  $
\begin{cases}
x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2} ,  & \text{if $x>0$ } \\
x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}

$f(x)=\int_{-1}^{0}(x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}) =\dfrac{1}{6}$

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{1+\sqrt{2}}(x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}) =\dfrac{5}{6}+\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$

but I just can not remember why use  $1+\sqrt{2}$
Reference answer is $1+\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper boundary $1+\sqrt 2$ comes from the solution of

$$x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}=0$$

Because the area is between $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis and the upper integral boundary is the root of $f(x)=0$.

Comment: It’s hard to think of it, my problem is not to try, my mind only thinks about what wolfram alpha is going on, how can I not count it, I don’t want to calculate the equation at all.

Comment: I have been bothering me for a long time, thank you very much, not sensitive to numbers, and relying on calculators. When the calculator is broken, it is very painful, don’t think about it, don’t try it, just think about the calculator, keep trying to calculate  Device

Comment: You are welcome